# 415 unsupported media type when adding through form-data from postman

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, controller, postman, blob

I am getting 415 unsupported media in postman while trying to insert data through form-data.
This is my controller for accepting input:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addPhoto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseDto addPhoto(@RequestBody int id,@RequestBody MultipartFile image )
        throws SerialException, SQLException, IOException {
    return visitorServiceLocal.addPhoto(image,id);
}
```

I am inserting data in postman using the body part,Its provided here:
[postman input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQsFW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are using @RequestBody instead of @RequestParam. Please try using @RequestParam. Below code works perfectly fine for me.

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public FileInformation uploadDoc(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception
    {
        return fileHandlingSgervice.uploadDoc(file);
    }
```

Postman
[image: postman screenshot]